# Refreshing listview after editing an item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a list which displays a list of books, but after editing the information about it i can't get the updated data in my listview. I tried to use listview.items.refresh(), ObservableCollection and INotifyPropertyChanged. If I press on update button again and close the pop-up it will show me the updated value

XAML:

```
                  <ListView x:Name="BooksView">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Expander Background="#e8f1f5" Width="700">
                                <Expander.Header >
                                    <controls:BookControl Book="{Binding  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=.}"/>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >

                                    <Button Content="Delete" Style="{StaticResource OptionsBtn}"  Background="#27496d" Click="ButtonDelete_OnClick"/>

                                    <Button Content="Update" Style="{StaticResource OptionsBtn}" Click="ButtonUpdate_OnClick" />

                                    <Button Content="More" Style="{StaticResource OptionsBtn}"  Background="#70416d"/>

                                    <Button Content="History" Style="{StaticResource OptionsBtn}" Background="#420000" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Expander>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

CS:

```
   public partial class AdminHome : Window
{
    private Client _client;
    private ObservableCollection<Book> _books;
    private readonly ServiceClient _serviceClient = new ServiceClient();

    public AdminHome(Client client)
    {
        this._client = client;
        InitializeComponent();
        _books = _serviceClient.BooksList();
        BooksView.ItemsSource = _books;
    }

    private void ButtonUpdate_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedBook = BooksView.SelectedItem as Book;
        var updateBookPage = new UpdateBook(selectedBook);
        updateBookPage.Closed += UpdateBookPage_Closed;
        updateBookPage.Show();
        BooksView.Items.Refresh();

    }
}
```

Model :

```
    public class Book : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string UniqueCode { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }

    private string editure;

    public string Editure
    {
        get => editure;
        set
        {
            if (editure == value) return;
            editure = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Comment: What do `UpdateBook` and `UpdateBookPage_Closed` do? Your code sample is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me, but I don't understand your code at all... using ObservableCollection seems the best approach :

Your class may be something like that (in my example, I just put ID and Name to make shorter

```
public class Book() : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
    private long id=-1;
    public long ID { get { return this.id; } set { this.id = value; } }

    private string name="";
    public string Name 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return this.name; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            this.name = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); // When you edit a book's name, the update will be done automatically by binding.
        }
    }
}
```

Then your ViewModel may be like that :

```
public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string nomPropriete)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nomPropriete));
}
private Book selectedBook{get;set;}
public Book SelectedBook{get{return this.selectedBook;}set{this.selectedBook=value;}}

private List<Book> selectedBooks = new List<Book>();
public List<Book> SelectedBooks
{
   get { return selectedBooks; }
   set
   {
       selectedBooks = value;
   }
}
private ObservableCollection<Book> listBooks = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
public ObservableCollection<Book> ListBooks
{
   get { return listBooks; }
   set
   {
       listBooks = value;
       this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ListBooks"); //list will be updated when you add/remove items in it
   }
}
```

Then XAML will be like that :

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewBooks" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook}"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListBooks}" SelectionChanged="ListBooks_SelectionChanged" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name"/>
            //Add as many columns as you want
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Here you bind the listview to "ListBooks". Everytime you will modify the list (add/remove elements, or edit name), the lsit will be updated without needing any code.

Then the function `ListBooks_SelectionChanged` allows you to update the list SelectedBooks. So when you want to make another function, you just need to check which elements are selected through SelectedListBooks.

```
private void ListBooks_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    contexte.SelectedBooks = ListViewBook.SelectedItems.Cast<Book>().ToList();
}
```

Something else, if you somewhere need to display a new list of books in the same view, never do ListBooks = new ObservableCollection(), you will lose your binding, and nothing will work (it took me a while to understand that). When you need to do that, better do the following :

```
ListBooks.Clear();
foreach(Book book in newListToDisplay)
{
    ListBooks.Add(book);
}
```

I also would advise you to read about MVVM, will help you in your code structure.
Last thing, I see something missing in your code : DataContext. You need to define datacontext too, like "this.DataContext=this;" if you don't use MVVM

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried breakpoints to check if the item is even being changed? from what I can see it doesn't look like your doing anything with the updated book, try doing something like this.

```
var index = _books.IndexOf(selectedBook);
_books.Remove(selectedBook);
_books.Insert(index, updatedBook);
```

Also I'm not sure as I've not tested your code if the INotifyPropertyChanged class should actually be inherited in your ViewModel (AdminHome) not the Model (Book)

The way I have always done it is have my models that does not inherit INotifyPropertyChanged, then I have a separate file for my ViewModel that handles commands, loading data etc and have this inherit the INotifyPropertyChanged class then I bind that to the DataContext of my View.

Answer (score 0):

I write right away - this is not a good technique, but it should solve your problem.

```
        updateBookPage.Show();
        BooksView.ItemsSource = null;
        BooksView.ItemsSource = _books;
```

If you can, it's best to find the cause of the malfunction.
In fact, there can be two of them:

1. If you change the collection itself `_book`  and there is no reaction to this change, then you have duplication of collection instances somewhere. You display one instance, but edit another.
2. If you change the values of the properties of `Book`  and do not see these changes, then in the class `Book`  you do not have a complete implementation of INPC in all properties.
   Add raising PropertyChanged to each property.

Comment: I decided to slightly supplement the answer.   
If the option with the intermediate assignment to null does not work, then it definitely means that you have a confusion with the collection instances.